# Read unicode from JSON to String field using aeson

Tags: haskell, unicode, bytestring, aeson

I receive a JSON data using httpLbs and read it

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.UTF8 as LB

sendSimpleRequest :: Credentials -> IO LB.ByteString
sendSimpleRequest creds = do
    <...>
    let request = applyBasicAuth user pass $ fromJust $ parseUrl url
    manager <- newManager tlsManagerSettings
    response <- httpLbs request manager
    return $ responseBody response
```

After that, I can print the result with `putStr . LB.toString` and get `"summary":"Обсуждение рабочих вопросов"`.

However, when I try to use `aeson`'s `decode` to put this value into `data` and print it

```
data Fields = Fields
    { fi_summary :: String
    } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON Fields where parseJSON = genericParseJSON parseOptions
instance ToJSON Fields where toJSON = genericToJSON parseOptions

parseOptions :: Options
parseOptions = defaultOptions { fieldLabelModifier = drop 3 }

parseAndShow = putStr . show . fromJust . decode
```

I get escaped characters: `Fields {fi_summary = "\1054\1073\1089\1091\1078\1076\1077\1085\1080\1077 \1088\1072\1073\1086\1095\1080\1093 \1074\1086\1087\1088\1086\1089\1086\1074"}`

Seems like I need to configure `aeson` to correctly put `ByteString` into `String`, but I don't want to implement the `FromJSON` instance myself because I have a dozen more structures like `data Fields`. Changing the `fi_summary` type is also a possibility, but I had no luck with any so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're seeing escaped characters, then the data is in the string just fine. The default string `Show` instance prints all non-ASCII characters like this. So you're got the data, it's just a matter of trying to output it again appropriately.

You might try using `putStrLn` to print the string, or maybe write it to a text file. (I know sometimes `putStrLn` does strange things if the locale is set wrong...)

Comment: Yep, printing the field directly does it: `putStrLn . fi_summary`
I'm accepting the answer because I don't actually need the correct `show` behavior for my project, but is there a way to make `show` print unicode characters globally? (again, dozens of structures)

Comment: None that I can think of. You would have to somehow *undefine* the existing `Show` instance and then write a new one. I don't think it's technically possible to do that - but I may be mistaken...